Find and remove ASCI values from varchar
Context

Reading from CSV files using SQL Server 2016 (no format option available).

The files are crlf/windows and each value will be wrapped in double quotes. Files are located here, note that I changed them to crlf for consistency.


Problem
Every now and then specifically I see this often with numbers, when we attempt to do a replace(value, '"', '') and then cast to int, it will fail with error below
Error

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '331877
' to data type int.

But if we do a substring() it produces a value that cannot be cast to int.

Super hacky IMHO because you need to guess at the length of the string using len().

I have verified that the results of both replace and substring look exactly alike, but when I run a
nullif(replace(value, '"', ''), substring(value, 2, len(value)-2))

it claims they are different somehow. (crosses eyes) They look the same... they are the same type... they are the same, but nullif recognizes that something is wrong. My code is below. Perhaps there is something with the coalition??
bulk insert #tmp
    From 'C:\acquisition_samples.csv'
    WITH
        (
            CODEPAGE = '65001'
            ,FIRSTROW = 2
            ,FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
            ,ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A'  
            ,batchsize=10
            ,TABLOCK
        );
    -- DDL
    insert into acquisition_sample(fdc_id_of_sample_food, fdc_id_of_acquisition_food) -- UPDATE file name, and columns
        select
            nullif(REPLACE(t.fdc_id_of_sample_food, '"', ''), substring(t.fdc_id_of_sample_food,2,LEN(t.fdc_id_of_sample_food)-2))
            , nullif(REPLACE(t.fdc_id_of_acquisition_food, '"', ''), substring(t.fdc_id_of_acquisition_food,2,LEN(t.fdc_id_of_acquisition_food)-2)) as wtf
            , CAST(substring(t.fdc_id_of_sample_food,2,LEN(t.fdc_id_of_sample_food)-2) AS INT) 
            , t.fdc_id_of_acquisition_food
            , CAST(substring(t.fdc_id_of_acquisition_food,2,LEN(t.fdc_id_of_acquisition_food)-3) AS INT)
        from #tmp t



The posted error message is showing a space or space-like character at the end of the string being cast to INT - '331877 '. A regular space would not cause a conversion error, but other whitespace characters like a nonbreaking space will.  See this db<>fiddle. You need to figure out what this character is and eliminate it before the CAST().

Effectively it will break for any trailing non-printable characters except space - even tab, linefeed and carriage return will cause that error. You might also check the process you used to convert the files to CR-LF to see if it handles files that have mixed line breaks.

@AlwaysLearning and @T N, I do think it might be some kind of weird file symbol like a carriage return. Now that I look at the value I copied into my question it seems rather silly. The thing is it didn't print that way in the console. it printed the space to a new line, which I thought was odd, but thought it might just be MSSQL pushing it to a new line for formatting purposes.

Sounds like a carriage return or newline (line feed) character. Updated fiddle. A SELECT UNICODE(RIGHT(value, 1)) should identify the character.

Why not just use LTRIM(RTRIM(YourValue))

I did attempt LTrim(RTrim())  but that did not correct the issue because we didn't know what to trim and it didn't remove the carriage return without specifying.

Thanks to the hints from @AlwaysLearning and @T N
This now becomes obvious that the reason why we get a different value is that substring was removing the extra character, but replace was only targeting the double quotes I fed to it.
Discovering the correct code for the character(s).
UNICODE(RIGHT(value, 1))

Solution
REPLACE(Fieldname, CHAR(13), '')

This now becomes obvious that the reason why we get a different value is that substring was removing the extra character, but replace was only targeting the double quotes I fed to it.
I realized that the reason the text at the end of the line is pushed down by one line in the error console is that it's a carriage return.
This similar answer also helped.
CSV Carriage Return Character
